# In NextJs, how do I make a routing system similar to stackoverflow

Tags: next.js, nextjs-app-beta

I want the routes to work in a way that:

- Visiting `www.example.com/blog/12345` should redirect to `www.example.com/blog/12345/this-is-a-test`.
- Visiting `www.example.com/blog/12345/this-a-some-random-text-blahblahblah` should also redirect to `www.example.com/blog/12345/this-is-a-test`.
- Visiting `www.example.com/blog/12345/this-a-some-random-text-blahblahb/test/having-fun` should be 404 error.

The correct blog is always fetched using `id`, and the title of the blog is set as the second parameter in the URI based on the fetched data.

Right now, for this route:
`www.example.com/blog/12345/this-is-a-test`
I have this folder structure in the `app/` directory:

```
app/
  blog/
    [id]/
      [title]/
        page.tsx
```

From the `blog/[id]/[title]/page.tsx` file, I have access to both the `id` and `title`. Using the `id`, I can fetch and display some data. No problem, I don't need to use the `title`. The `title` is for SEO purposes, and I want to be able to change the `title` in the URI to the actual title of the resource after being fetched using `id`.

How do I achieve this? I may have to change the folder structure, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation'

export default function Page({ params }: { params: { id: string; title: string } }) {

  const expectedTitle = getTitleFromId(params.id) // get this from your db or whatever

  if (expectedTitle !== params.title) {
    redirect(`/blog/${params.id}/${expectedTitle}`)
  }

  return <div>My Post: {params.title}</div>
}
```

Refer: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/redirect, https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes

PS: might wanna make title optional if you want to handle `example.com/blog/12345` too.

Comment: But doesn't this make unnecessary requests to the database? If `params.title` was some random string, then makes a request to database to get actual title, checks it against the parameters, redirects to `/blog/123/expected-title`, then again makes a request to database, checks the title, renders page.

Comment: @SheikhAmeen Implement database caching. You can also do: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/caching